# Question concerning the domain of a function

Tags: special-functions

In the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(x)= 5x$  why is range not equal to co domain?
I don't understand why this is not a surjective function while the same function is surjective if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What's with the title? Could you explain a motivation?

Comment: If by "range" you mean "image" then the image is the multiples of five.  For example, $1$ is not in the image.  In this context the "codomain" would still be $\mathbb N$.  Whether or not the function is surjective on the reals has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I like pizza, but only when it is relevant to the question.

Comment: For example: if $f$ were surjective, there must be an $n$ from the domain such that $f(n) = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is defined on the natural numbers you have $im(f)=5\mathbb{N}=\{5,10,15,20,\dots\}$. If $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ then given any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a $y:=\frac{x}{5}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(y)=x$. Hence $f$ is surjective.